# Can I use Google Cardboard with non-NFC phones?

Tags: nfc, google-cardboard

I have recently got a hold of new phone which has 5 inch Full HD screen, so the first thing that I wanted to do is checking out the Google Cardboard VR.

But I recently learnt that my phone doesn't have NFC in it, and I heard Google Cardboard needs NFC to do some things.

So my question is, can I use Google Cardboard VR with my phone? If yes, then how can I?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, NFC is just used for auto-launching the app.

Comment: Thanks , i tried installing and launching app, but it shows 2-3 horizontal lines and nothing more, i dont have google cardboard VR headeset, i just tried installing app without VR headset. does google cardboard app must need cardboard Vr headset to start app ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NFC is used to auto-launch the application when inside a Google Cardboard device.

It's a way of the app to know that it is inside a cardboard device and it can launch the application in VR mode. When in VR mode, the display is split into two parts.

So, in short you can directly launch the application normally and select the cardboard demo app and then insert it inside the device.