# Google Cardboard magnet not working with Nexus 4

Tags: nexus-4, google-cardboard

I have bought Google Cardboard for my Nexus 4, but its side magnet to go inside the apps is not working. I don't know what's wrong. Can anyone help me?

Comment: That's very little to go on. Could you provide any more specifics? IIRC the magnet is observed with NFC, does NFC work on the Nexus?

Comment: Related, though different problem: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/101819/can-i-use-google-cardboard-with-non-nfc-phones (Nexus 4 supports NFC, but Cardboard can be used without NFC)

Comment: Yeah NFC works in my nexus 4

Comment: I have similar issue with the cardboard and Nexus 5X.

Answer (score 1):

I bought a cardboard, working with Nexus 4. It had the same problem as described, but I managed to solve it. see the picture attached, I extend the moving range far more 50 mm, and it works(clicking now!)[image: Magnet not working fixed by]

Answer (score 0):

In my experience it's very finicky. Try entering a cardboard app and using the center dividing line on the screen as a guide to positioning. If that still doesn't work, I usually move the phone left in very small increments until I can get it to work.

It may also depend on the manufacturer of the Cardboard set. The magnet is using the phones magnetic sensors to trigger a command. If the magnet they provided isn't strong enough or is positioned incorrectly, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have dark shader + N4. I had to remove the magnet and wave it near the phone. Ugly but effective.